# Terraform Azure App Service - ip_restrictions

Tags: terraform, azure-web-app-service, ip-restrictions

I am trying to set the IP restrictions block in my Azure App Service App

When performing the Terraform plan or apply, I receive the following error:
**Error: azurerm_app_service.app-service-1: : invalid or unknown key: ip_restriction**

I used **ip_restriction** per Terraform Documentation for App Service (Web Apps) Resources

**Here is the AppService deployment code i am using:**

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "app-service-1" {
  name                    = "${var.app_service_1}"
  location                = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.core-rg.location}"
  resource_group_name     = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.core-rg.name}"
  app_service_plan_id     = "${data.azurerm_app_service_plan.app-service-plan-1.id}"
  https_only              = "True"
  enabled                 = "True"
  client_affinity_enabled = "True"

  site_config {
    always_on                 = "True"
    #default_documents        = ""
    dotnet_framework_version  = "v4.0"
    #http2_enabled            = ""
    #ip_restriction           = ""
    #java_version             = ""
    #java_container           = ""
    #java_container_version   = ""
    managed_pipeline_mode     = "Integrated"
    min_tls_version           = "1.2"
    #php_version              = ""
    #python_version           = ""
    remote_debugging_enabled  = "False"
    #remote_debugging_version = ""
    scm_type                  = "None"
    use_32_bit_worker_process = "False"
    websockets_enabled        = "True"
    #ftps_state               = ""
  }

  app_settings {
    "KeyVaultURI" = ""
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "6.9.1"
  }

  ip_restriction {
   "ip_address"     = ""
   }
```

Thank you

Comment: I believe you need to have a value assigned to `ip_address`.  What happens when you put a valid IP address in there?

Comment: Yes i had an IP in there, i removed it for this post. The error i receive from Terraform Apply, is claiming  "invalid or unknown key: ip_restriction" as if it is not a supported command in Terraform, dispite the terraform documentation. Has anyone succesfully used  ip_restriction {
   "ip_address"     = "1.2.3.4"
   }. Documentation states subnetmask is optional, but first we need Terraform to recognize ip_restriction as a valid command

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For those interested, here is the method to use ipRestrictions in Terraform**

ip Restrictions is part of the Site_Config {}

See how to use below:

**AppService.tf:**

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "app-service-1" {
  name                    = "${var.app_service_1}"
  location                = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.core-rg.location}"
  resource_group_name     = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.core-rg.name}"
  app_service_plan_id     = "${data.azurerm_app_service_plan.app-service-plan-1.id}"
  https_only              = "True"
  enabled                 = "True"
  client_affinity_enabled = "True"
  site_config {
    always_on                 = "True"
    #default_documents        = ""
    dotnet_framework_version  = "v4.0"
    #http2_enabled            = ""
    #ip_restriction           = ""
    #java_version             = ""
    #java_container           = ""
    #java_container_version   = ""
    managed_pipeline_mode     = "Integrated"
    min_tls_version           = "1.2"
    #php_version              = ""
    #python_version           = ""
    remote_debugging_enabled  = "False"
    #remote_debugging_version = ""
    scm_type                  = "None"
    use_32_bit_worker_process = "False"
    websockets_enabled        = "True"
    #ftps_state               = ""
    ip_restriction {
      ip_address  = "${var.ip_address_1}"
    }
    ip_restriction {
      ip_address  = "${var.ip_address_2}"
    }
    ip_restriction {
      ip_address  = "${var.ip_address_3}"
    }
  }
  app_settings {
    "KeyVaultURI" = ""
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "6.9.1"
    }
  }
```

Comment: ip_address has to be CIDR notation and you cant set a name or set IP6 addresses which is a shame

Answer (score 10):

@jamies answer is unfortunately incorrect IP_restriction is not a list taking one or more but a repeatable block.

@gvazzana is the correct format.
However, there is a trap.. that will cause the error you are seeing.

In Tf we are used to typing IP address's in full CIDR format eg 10.23.97.201/23 or 192.68.50.0/24, the azure portal for this section even displays them like this.

But for this particular block, in terraform, you have to do them old school.  eg:

```
site_config {
  # For a single IP address
  ip_restriction {
      ip_address = "81.145.174.78"
      } 
  ip_restriction {
  # For an address range 
      ip_address = "10.240.101.0"
      subnet_mask = "255.255.255.0"
     }
}
```

This is of course a pain if you have a long list of address's and ranges.

Now that terraform version 0.12.0 is upon us we should be able to take advantage of the new `dynamic` block styles and `cidrhost` and `cidrmask` functions in order to simplify things.

eg:

```
dynamic "ip_restriction" {
for_each = var.ip_address_list
  content {
    ip_address  = cidrhost(ip_restriction.value,0)
    subnet_mask = cidrmask(ip_restriction.value)
  }
}
```

tested with
Terraform v0.12.13

Comment: Thank you, great info. Switching to tf v12 from v11 is going to be tough. So many changes will have to happen, and will break code I’m sure!

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Except I think the function for subnet_mask needs to be `cdrnetmask(...)`. I couldn't get it to work unless I changed it like this:

`content {
   ip_address  = cidrhost(ip_restriction.value,0)
   subnet_id = cidrnetmask(ip_restriction.value)
}`

I found this in [the docs here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/cidrnetmask.html).

Comment: @jamie's answer is actually valid.  It's a [documented and working alternative syntax for for repeated blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/attr-as-blocks.html#defining-a-fixed-object-collection-value).  In this situation it's even preferable since using a dynamic block does not properly remove the ip_restriction settings since it doesn't explicitly set it to an empty block.

Answer (score 3):

So you are running into a syntax error. The documentation can be confusing to read as I have learned over the last year. If you read the section on [ip_restriction](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html#ip_restriction) it says that it takes one or more. This means that it expects an array.

There is also a section of the documentation that tells you that it inside the array it expects an object that has the properties of ip_address and subnet_mask. That is [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html#ip_address)

So to fix your issue you need the following for ip_restriction.

```
ip_restriction = [
    {
        ip_address = "10.0.0.0"
    }
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the information. That is indeed confusing and almost contradictions information from Terraform! I believe that will resolve the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: If this answers your question, please be sure mark it as the answer as it will help others know.

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this live, and it does not accept that format either    Error: azurerm_app_service.app-service-1: : invalid or unknown key: ip_restriction